# Inequality involving real numbers with rational powers

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If $ a, b, c$ are positive real numbers, not all equal, and **n is a negative rational** number then show that: $$  a^n (a-b)(a-c)+ b^n(b-c)(b-a)+c^n(c-a)(c-b) > 0 $$ I started by proving this for the first case $a=b$ which was easy because then the above expression transforms into $ c^n(c-a)^2$ which is definitely positive. But I am stuck in the next case where I take $a> b > c.$ Here: $$a^n (a-b)(a-c)+ b^n(b-c)(b-a) = (a-b)[a^n(a-c)-b^n(b-c)] $$ For this since $a>b$ and $n<0$ , hence $a^n < b^n$, but, $ a-c > b-c$. I am unable to proceed further. Any help would be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: This is Schur's inequality [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_inequality].  Instead of combining the first two terms, if you try with the last two, you will have success.  In fact $x \to x^n$ can be replaced by any monotonic function $f(x)$, and similar proof will go through.

Comment: Thank you, was able to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved it: $$ a^n (a-b)(a-c)+ b^n(b-c)(b-a)+c^n(c-a)(c-b) = a^n (a-b)(a-c)+\color{red}{(b-c)[c^n(a-c)-b^n(a-b)]} $$Now , $ a>b>c $ implies that $a-c > a-b$ and $n<0$ implies that $ c^n>b^n.$ Therefore, $ c^n(a-c)-b^n(a-b) >0.$ Also,$(a-b),(a-c),(b-c)$ are all $>0$.Thus the answer.